# Configure Springboot Jaeger and RSocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, opentracing, jaeger, rsocket

I have Springboot Webflux main application that talks to other services using RSocket and I want to configure the stack so I want to see the traces looking like this:

```
main app
-- app1
-- app2
  -- app3
  -- app4
```

As today I need to check each app to check the flow

```
main app
app1
app2
app3
app4
```

I'm using implementation `'io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter'` dependency

How does one integrate opentracing (jaeger) with RSocket? I saw that for WebClient, you have autoconfiguration but found little or no instructions on how to do it besides [Tracking-Zipkin](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket/blob/master/Extensions/Tracing-Zipkin.md) page which I don't really know how to procced from that.